# Disable gridview rows based on database table column value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a gridview which  is being loaded from database table.
There is one column in the table named 'valid',whose values are 'Y' or 'N'.
Now, what I want to do is, to check if the value of 'valid' is Y, then the whole record  in that row should appear as disabled when loading the gridview.

How to proceed with that? should I write a procedure for this or it can be done from code behind?

Note: the column Valid is not a part of gridview.

Comment: why Valid is not a part of gridview?

Comment: Valid column not required to be displayed in the grid view.
Valid column has been put in the database table only for the disable/ enable row in the gridview

Comment: you can add this in hidden field and get in RowDataBound event as shown in shekhar answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `RowDataBound` event of gridview to disable rows.
Note that if you use `databound columns` then it is rendered in `tr` and `td` then you need to find the cell and then set the disable property.

```
protected void gvEntity_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       //CheckBox cbAttachClrReq = (CheckBox) e.Row.FindControl("chkAdd");
       //check the value here and set enable property
       e.Row.Enabled = false;

    }

}
```

As  @Hanlet Escaño has suggested you can add the field value in the same column as follows

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" 
             Value='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" 
             Value='<%# Eval("valid") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

and get the hidden field value in row-databound event as follows

```
protected void gvEntity_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       HiddenField Hf = (HiddenField) e.Row.FindControl("HiddenField1");
       if(Hf.Value=="Y")
           e.Row.Enabled = false;

    }

}
```

Comment: +1, but I think the OP mentioned the field is not part of the GridView. So maybe if that chkAdd is a hidden field instead this could work.

Comment: Yes it would be good idea or he can use linq to filter data from his source on the basis of identity column.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, am trying to implement as you suggested. will revert soon.

Comment: I am getting this error: 'Value' is not a valid property on 'Label'

Comment: Ok, am using Text instead Value

Answer (score 3):

Try the following.

This example gets the `DataRowView` per record and then extracts the `valid` column from the underlying datasource to test against.

```
 protected void grdDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           var dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView; 

              if(Convert.ToString(dr["valid"]) == 'Y')
                  e.Row.Enabled = false;

       }
  }
```

and the markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDetails" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="grdDetails_RowDataBound"
```

Comment: I misunderstood initially. This answer should fix your problem.